# ESP HTTPS OTA Begin failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, esp32, ota, esp-idf

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on an ESP-IDF project where I'm attempting to perform OTA (Over-The-Air) firmware updates using HTTPS. Specifically, I'm using the advanced HTTPS OTA example code provided by ESP-IDF.

My goal is to update the firmware on an ESP32 device by downloading the firmware binary file from an S3 bucket hosted on AWS. I have ensured that the S3 bucket has public access, and I've placed my helloworld.bin file in it.

However, when I run the advanced HTTPS OTA example code and replace the URL with the URL of my S3 bucket, I encounter the following error:

```
I (19042) advanced_https_ota_example: Starting Advanced OTA example
E (19052) esp_https_ota: No option for server verification is enabled in esp_http_client config.
E (19062) advanced_https_ota_example: ESP HTTPS OTA Begin failed
```

It seems that the ESP HTTPS OTA process is failing at the beginning stage. I've tried to troubleshoot this issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to address this error? Additionally, if there's a better or alternative way to implement OTA updates on ESP32 devices, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights.Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Best regards,
Rahul B.

Comment: Make sure you have the full x509 certificate bundle enabled via config option [CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CERTIFICATE_BUNDLE](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-mbedtls-certificate-bundle). Also - your URL is HTTPS, not HTTP, right?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the full x509 certificate bundle is enabled using the config option CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CERTIFICATE_BUNDLE. Additionally, the URL I am using is indeed HTTPS, not HTTP.

However, if there are any additional suggestions or insights you have regarding this issue, I would greatly appreciate them.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: OK. Then we need to see your code, preferably in the form of a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)